# How to write in math environment in \xy matrix

Tags: math-mode, xymatrix

I want to write `$\alpha$` in place of `a` in `Z[a]` and `Z` as set of integer symbol. But when I'm trying it in math environment using `$` symbol it is giving error. Please Help.

```
\begin{displaymath}
\xymatrixcolsep{4.5pc}
\hspace{-1.75cm} \xymatrix{
  & &  Z[x] \ar[dl] \ar[dr] & \\ 
   &  Z[a]  \ar[dr] & & Z[m] \ar[dl]  \\
  & & Z/NZ  & &
}
\end{displaymath}
```

Comment: It is in math mode `displaymath`. Just type `\alpha`.

Comment: For the set of integers, usually we use `\mathbb{Z}` from  amsfonts` package.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you are adding unnecessary column on the left. Your diagram requires only 3 columns.

The `\xymatrix{}` requires a math mode, that is, should be used within `$ $` (inline) or `\[ \]` (displayed) (or equivalently, within `equation*` or `equation` environment).

So, you don't need (in fact, you can not) use `$ $` inside any matrix entry. Just type as you want: `\alpha`.

Finally, to denote integers set, usually we use `\mathbb{}` font from `amsfonts` package.

*Extra tip:* you can control the distance between columns/rows in the diagram using `@C<distance>` or `@R<distance>`. For example, `@C4.5pc`.

**Full code**

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{xypic}

\begin{document}
\[ 
\xymatrix@C4.5pc{
                           & \mathbb{Z}[x] \ar[dl] \ar[dr] &                       \\ 
\mathbb{Z}[\alpha] \ar[dr] &                               & \mathbb{Z}[m] \ar[dl] \\
                           & \mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z}
}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]