# Adding a symbol to the top of a vertex in a connected tree

Tags: trees, xy-pic, xymatrix

I have a code for a tree

```
\[
\xymatrix@-1.25pc{
   *={\bullet}  &  &*={\bullet} &  
   \frm{}\\
   &*={\bullet}\ar@{-}[lu] \ar@{-}[ru]& & 
 }
\]
```

which will produce this

[image: complete_tree]

as its output. However, I would like to number the top nodes as follows:

[image: complete_tree-2]

yet I would like the line segments to be connected to the center of the vertices. I tried replacing `\bullet` with `\stackrel{i}{\bullet}` 
as follows:

```
\[
\xymatrix@-1.25pc{
*={\stackrel{1}{\bullet}}  &  &*={\stackrel{2}{\bullet}} &  
\frm{}\\
&*={\bullet}\ar@{-}[lu] \ar@{-}[ru]& & 
 }
\]
```

but the nodes are no longer connected to the edges:

[image: complete-tree-3]

which is not what I want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A solution with Ti*K*z. (I never used the `xy` package).

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{%
pics/bullet/.style args={#1,#2}{
    code={
    \node at (0,1) [draw,circle,fill,minimum size=2mm,inner sep=0pt,label={$#1$}](#1){};
    \node at (2,1) [draw,circle,fill,minimum size=2mm,inner sep=0pt,,label={$#2$}](#2){};
    \node at (1,0) [draw,circle,fill,minimum size=2mm,inner sep=0pt](bb){};
    \draw (bb)--(#1) (bb)--(#2);
    }}}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\pic at (0,0) {bullet={1,2}};
\pic at (3,0) {bullet={3,4}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I have leaved the question because I have thinked that the best solution was TikZ. Very good.

Comment: @Sebastiano, thank you.

Comment: :o) it is necessary, for me, many time to create with xy package to give an answer. But with xy package it is possible to draw two trees.

Answer (score 4):

The XY syntax is quite concise and powerful, but it takes some getting used to.  But it's easy to add the labels relative to the position of the bullet using the `\save` and `\restore` function of XY. See my answer to [Pushout commutative diagram](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/493810/2693) for a detailed explanation of how that works.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\begin{document}

\[
\xymatrix@-1.25pc{
   *={\bullet}\save+<0ex,2ex>*={1}\restore  &  &*={\bullet}\save+<0ex,2ex>*={2}\restore&  
   \frm{}\\
   &*={\bullet}\ar@{-}[lu] \ar@{-}[ru]& & 
 }
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]